# SSH/SCP filebrowser supporting server hopping

Tags: ssh, files, scp

To access our file server here, I need to connect first to a server which is public available and then open a second ssh connection to that server. If I need to copy files, I first need to copy them from the file server to the public available server. Then I can use a tool like Cyberduck (MAC) or WinSCP on (WINDOWS) to confortable browse and download the files. Is there a tool available where I can configure to connect directly to the target server?

Answer (score 1):

You can first create an ssh tunnel with `Putty` or one of its utilities, `Plink`. With Plink you can do

```
plink.exe -L 2200:yoursecondserver:22 you@yourpublicserver
```

With Mac you probably can just replace `plink.exe` with command `ssh`.

After that you can connect your Cyberduck or WinSCP to `localhost:2200` and access your second server over an ssh tunnel.

To make this easier, you can write a script. For example in Mac, something like

```
#!/bin/sh
ssh -L 2200:yoursecondserver:22 you@yourpublicserver
/path/to/cyberduck &
```

should do it. :)